# Scala - finding sequence members that are of a certain type's child type

Tags: scala, type-systems

I have the following situation:

Java lib class:

```
class LibClass {
  ArrayList<LibClass> children;
}
```

my program Scala code:

```
abstract class MyClass extends LibClass {
  def boom { }
  def boomMyClassInstances  // ???
}

class Lala extends MyClass
class Hoho extends MyClass
```

The question is: in the method `boomMyClassInstances` what is the most Scala-ish way to get all the `children` of `MyClass`, stored in the `children` `ArrayList` so that I can call the common `boom` method upon them all?

My try is:

```
def boomMyClassInstances {
  children.toArray.map { case mc: MyClass => mc.boom }
}
```

Is this a correct approach? Will it pick all the children of `MyClass` and this is the right Scala way for that, or do I have to say something about type bounds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out `GenTraversableLike.collect`. Its signature essentially is `Traversable[A].collect[B <: A](f: A ~> B): Traversable[B]`, that is, it takes a collection with elements of type `A` and a **partial** function `f` from `A` to `B`, and returns a collection of static element-type `B`, where `B` is a subtype of `A`.

```
val myClassInstances: List[MyClass] =
  children.toList.collect{case mc: MyClass => mc}
```

Since `map` expects a total function, your try above will fail with an `scala.MatchError` in case `children` does not only contain instances of `MyClass`. You can work around this by using `Option` or `flatMap`, but `collect` seems to be the most Scala-ish way of achieving what you want.

Answer (score 5):

```
import collection.JavaConverters._

children.asScala.foreach { 
  case mc: MyClass => mc.boom 
  case _ => ()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a type expert, so I can't say definitively that your solution will work, however it does seem that it should work. It has the advantage of being straightforward, which is always good.

You do need to add a catch-all case though (so as to not get a `scala.MatchError`).

```
case _ => // do nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to `collect` the relevant portion:

```
children.iterator collect { case mc: MyClass => mc } foreach (_.boom())
```